# How to make HoloMap to explore PNG images; <img> components of DIV not displaying

Tags: python, html, panel, holoviews

I would like to make a simple app to explore a set of PNG files.  In general, there will be several selection widgets (e.g. for sex and handedness), and a PNG file to display for each combination of selections.

I am trying to do this  using `HoloMap` with a dictionary of `holoviews.Div` objects, so that the interactivity does not depend on having a live Python server.

The individual cells of the HoloMap display correctly, but the interactive `HoloMap` does not display the image components of the `Div` objects.

To demonstrate, I make a `HoloMap` to explore two PNG files, A or B.

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")  # To render in Notebook environment.

# Define format template for html div to display a figure.
# See https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Div.html.
div_format = """
        <figure>
        <img src=" {pic} " height='200' width='200'>
        <figcaption> {caption} </figcaption>
        """

# Map to URLs of two images.
pic_dict = {"A": "https://assets.holoviews.org/logo/holoviews_color_icon_500x500.png",
            "B": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"}

# Map to holoviews div objects for the images.
div_map = {key: hv.Div(div_format.format(pic=pic,
                                         caption="Figure "+key)) \
           for key, pic in pic_dict.items()}

holomap = hv.HoloMap(div_map, kdims="Figure")

holomap["A"]
# Shows PNG A and caption "Figure A".
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can also display `holomap["B"]`.

The `holomap` as a whole lets us interactively explore the figure captions (with a selection widget it generates).  However, the images themselves are not displayed in the interactive `HoloMap`--is this a bug?  If so, is there a work-around?  Or a better way to explore a set of images?

```
holomap
# Shows interactive display with figure caption and select widget, but no PNG.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `HoloMap`, an interactive image explorer could potentially be built directly from [bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html) widgets, with a little [javascript](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0) to change the image to reflect user selection.

This solution uses `bokeh` and `javascript` directly instead of relying on [holoviews](https://holoviews.org) to do that under the hood.

For example, to explore two PNG files by selecting 'A' or 'B':

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div, Select
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show

# Map to URLs of two images.
pic_dict = {"A": "https://assets.holoviews.org/logo/holoviews_color_icon_500x500.png",
            "B": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"}

option_keys = list(pic_dict.keys())
option_values = list(pic_dict.values())

# Make widget to display html, set to show first URL.
bk_html = Div(text='<img src="' + option_values[0] + '"/>')

# Make widget to select key from pic_dict.
bk_select = Select(options=option_keys, value=option_keys[0], title="Image selection")

# Link select-widget value to html-widget text, to show selected image.
bk_select.js_on_change(
    'value',
    CustomJS(
        args={"html": bk_html},
        code=f"""
            console.log('Entering bk_select jscallback.');
            // Array of URLs corresponding to this.options.
            const option_lookup = {option_values};
            
            // Look up URL corresponding to chosen option.
            var option_index = this.options.indexOf(this.value);
            var url = option_lookup[option_index];
            
            // Set HTML text to display image at URL.
            html.text = '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
            console.log('Set image to ', html.text);
        """
    )
)

# Lay out widgets in a column.
layout = column(bk_select, bk_html)

# To display Bokeh output inline in a Jupyter notebook:
output_notebook(hide_banner=True)

# Display the layout.
show(layout)
```

[image: Select widget showing option A, above image of holoviews icon]